# When can one find logs for Vertex AI Batch Prediction jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I couldn't find relevant information in the Documentation. I have tried all options and links in the batch transform pages.

Answer (score 4):

They can be found, but unfortunately not via any links in the Vertex AI console.

Soon after the batch prediction job fails, go to Logging -> Logs Explorer and create a query like this, replacing YOUR_PROJECT with the name of your gcp project:

`logName:"projects/YOUR_PROJECT/logs/ml.googleapis.com"`

First look for the same error reported by the Batch Prediction page in the Vertex AI console: "Job failed. See logs for full details."

The log line above the "Job Failed" error will likely report the real reason your batch prediction job failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that just going to Cloud logger after batch prediction job fails and clicking run query shows the error details

Answer (score 0):

The container logs are now exported to the user project in logs explorer.